# How to Print Four Columns of Data

Tags: java, arrays, multiple-columns

I have an array of data that i'm trying to put into a format such as...

```
Frequencies:
 1 (221)-   12 (229)+   23 (230)+   34 (223)-   
 2 (229)+   13 (235)+   24 (236)+   35 (237)+   
 3 (217)-   14 (225)-   25 (241)+   36 (238)+   
 4 (201)-   15 (223)-   26 (251)+   37 (233)+   
 5 (228)-   16 (238)+   27 (244)+   38 (219)-   
 6 (235)+   17 (232)+   28 (224)-   39 (234)+   
 7 (229)+   18 (240)+   29 (231)+   40 (229)+   
 8 (227)-   19 (217)-   30 (225)-   41 (263)+   
 9 (200)-   20 (198)-   31 (230)+   42 (221)-   
10 (211)-   21 (252)+   32 (226)-   43 (243)+   
11 (221)-   22 (228)-   33 (215)-   44 (227)-
```

What I can't figure out is how do I go down 11, then go to a new column, go down 11, and so on? Thanks for the time, oh it's java.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a 1D array that you are attempting to organize into columns for display. This can be tricky sometimes, but basically it comes down to this:

1. Create a way to format a single element to a fixed-width string.
2. Create a way to determine what element corresponds to a given row and column.
3. Output one row at a time.

So, starting with the formatting, for example (pretend `Element` is the thing you're trying to print):

```
class Element {
    // obviously i don't know what you're data format is; these
    // are just for illustrative purposes.
    int getIndex ();
    int getValue ();
    char getSign ();
}

void printElement (PrintWriter out, Element e) {
    // column width is 2+1+3+1+1 = 8
    out.printf("%2d(%3d)%c", e.getIndex(), e.getValue(), e.getSign());
}
```

See [*Format String Syntax*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more information on the format strings you can specify to [`PrintWriter.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Then, since you can only print one row at a time, you need to be able to determine the index of the element given a row and column number. This requires you to be able to calculate the number of rows ahead of time. So say you have a `ArrayList<Element> elems`:

```
int rows = elems.size() / 4;
```

Now you output each row, one at a time, using `rows` as the offset between adjacent elements in a row:

```
PrintWriter out = System.out; // or whatever

for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++ r) {
   for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++ c) {
      int index = c * rows + r; 
      if (index < elems.size()) { 
          printElement(out, elems.get(index)); // print data
          out.print("  "); // column spacer
      }
   }
   out.println(); // line ending after each row
}
```

Side note: Of course, in the (rare, these days) situation that your sole output is to a proper terminal, you could also use e.g. [curses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) to explicitly set output row and columns on the screen. However, that's probably not the situation you are in.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void genStats(int[] array)
{
    int mod = array.length / 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < mod; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " " + array[i + mod*1]
                + " " + array[i + mod*2] + " " + array[i + mod*3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last row if `array.length` was not a multiple of 4. Also, in the case of your example `int[]`, it would not guarantee fixed width columns (e.g. printing `1` vs. `1000`).